# Visual Studio 15.9.3 breaks web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have a 15 year old web forms app targeting .NET 4.6.1 that I'm maintaining, and I recently upgraded my laptop to VS 15.9.3. A release build of this app with 15.9.3 no longer fires the `Application_Start` event on production servers (running .NET 4.7.2). It runs locally just fine and I frequently deployed production builds from this laptop prior to the upgrade.

My desktop computer is still running VS 15.8, and a production build there works fine. The source code is the same between these machines, only the VS versions differ.

Symptoms and attempts at remedies:

1. I cleaned out all old files from production and tried setting it up from scratch. No dice.
2. Setup new application under IIS using the same build, but the outcome is the same.
3. Nothing in the event logs about any errors, except for the error that gets raised when some pages try to access state that's initialized in `Application_Start`.
4. I try to log some messages and even raise an exception right at the start of `Application_Start`, and I don't see anything, so `Application_Start` is definitely not running.

What can I do to further diagnose the problem? I haven't been able to find anything about this online, or why the newest VS release suddenly doesn't work.

Barring any remedies, any suggestions for downgrading VS instead of completely uninstalling and reinstalling the older VS?

Edit: now even reverting my laptop to VS 15.8.9 did not roll back the problem, so I've disassembled a build from both machines. There are few differences, basically the build number of a dependent assembly, the module version identifier, the comment designating the "image base":

Not working build:

```
// Image base: 0x055E0000
```

Working build:

```
// Image base: 0x052D0000
```

As far as I understand, none of these differences should have any observable effect. I then disassembled the dependent assembly that's built alongside the ASP.NET app, and it has the above differences and a few more related to the offsets for static field initializers. So I still have no idea why this might be happening.

Edit 2: it seems the issue is in the final aspnet_merge step while trying to merge the precompiled web forms. The merge fails in finding any assemblies to merge, suggesting that precompilation may have failed.

Comment: Do you run the app on IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008R2 for production, VS-builtin IIS express when running locally. Running locally is no issue, it's the production build that's the issue.

Comment: Is it `WebForm` site or `Web Application`? If it is `WebForm` then it is more than strange. VS is just an *editor*. Yes, very sophisticated editor but `WebForm` pages compile by .NET on IIS, not by VS.

Comment: It's a web application consisting of web forms. I have a publishing profile that precompiles all forms into a set of dlls. Clearly the VS 15.9.x series have updated the compilers and something about the code they emit is broken. I have no idea what could be wrong here, but I see the same behaviour across staging and production servers, all of which run .NET 4.7.2 on Windows Server 2008r2.

Comment: Just upgraded to 15.9.4 but the same symptoms. Looks like a complete uninstall and reinstall of of VS 15.8 is in my future.

Comment: Check `targetFramework` settings in developer and production application pools

Comment: Target is 4.6.1 everywhere.